# How to parametrize grouping?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the code to group by a given attribute. It works fine when I'm giving the exact attribute name. However I'd like to parametrize to set up the attribute name by which grouping will be, using Javascript xsltProcessor.setParameter.

As far as I know XSLT 1.0 doesn't allow to use either a variable or parameter in xsl:key match or use attribute. So if I can't parametrize by this way, I guess, I need to write so many XSL files as many group by attributes I want to use. If anyone can give me a trick or a resolution it is deeply appreciated.

Here is the xls giving the attribute exactly, which works fine:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="groupName" match="stickieshighlights/item" use="@color"/>
    <xsl:key name="eachitem" match="stickieshighlights/item" use="concat(@color,'|', @id)"/>

    <xsl:template match="stickieshighlights">
        <stickieshighlights>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="item[generate-id()=generate-id(key('groupName',@color)[1])]" mode="groupby"/>
        </stickieshighlights>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="groupby">
        <color name="{@color}">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="key('groupName',@color)[generate-id()=generate-id(key('eachitem',concat(@color,'|', @id))[1])]" mode="list"/>
        </color>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="list">
        <item id="{@id}" icon="{@icon}" date="{@date}" tags="{@tags}" url="{@url}" title="{@title}" content="{@content}" >
        </item>
    </xsl:template>   

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

here is my trying to use a parameter, but I get an error: key can't contain variable in expressions.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="group_By" />

    <xsl:key name="groupName" match="stickieshighlights/item" use="$group_By"/>
    <xsl:key name="eachitem" match="stickieshighlights/item" use="concat($group_By,'|', @id)"/>

    <xsl:template match="stickieshighlights">
        <stickieshighlights>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="item[generate-id()=generate-id(key('groupName',$group_By)[1])]" mode="groupby"/>
        </stickieshighlights>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="groupby">
        <xsl:element name="{$group_By}" > 
        <xsl:attribute name="{{$group_By}}"><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></xsl:attribute>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="key('groupName',$group_By)[generate-id()=generate-id(key('eachitem',concat($group_By,'|', @id))[1])]" mode="list"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="list">
        <item id="{@id}" icon="{@icon}" color="{@color}" date="{@date}" tags="{@tags}" url="{@url}" title="{@title}" content="{@content}" >
        </item>
    </xsl:template>   

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```